# React router: how to abort transition onEnter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there any way to abort transition to the next route using it's params?
In onEnter handler for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `history` instance, the best way to do this is to call `history.goBack()` after the transition completes.